# How to win on Might & Magic Heroes VI - Haven - Something Is Rotten campaign map

Tags: might-and-magic-heroes-6

I've tried the map three times already and lost each time. Played on easy difficulty always.

I tried following the conflux advice but the enemies are still eventually overrunning me with superior forces.

Didn't take the fort to the south so that the south enemies remain passive until I can take out the enemies in the east. Done the griffin quest as soon as I cleared the main base area.

After that I went directly for the east enemy but their forces were already superior to mine. I think danger level high. And there was no way I could have taken 2 high level fights one after the other to take their castle.

I was forced to retreat to my castle to build my forces but as time passed I got attacked by both enemies and in the end, after multiple fights, they won.

It is pretty obvious that the more time passes on this map the less chance of winning there is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How fast are you at attacking? In general, speed is absolutely essential in campaigns, as the opponents often start with much more stuff than you, you must conquer a majority quickly to even the odds, before being overwhelmed.

One important general tip: recruit secondary heroes to collect resources and capture mines, don't waste your main heroes movement on that. So, you destroy a monster camp, then move on with the main hero and let another hero collect all the stuff. This saves a lot of time on your main hero to move forward. Only collect with your main hero, when the monsters guarded an artifact you wanted to use.

The strategy on this map is pretty simple, collect everything around your starting area, especially the troops, then immediately move east to conquer the first stronghold town, this should all happen in week 1. On easy difficulty you should have no problems defeating the opponents with minimal losses by using your sisters to heal. After you conquered the first town, immediately move southwest to the 2nd stronghold, conquer that, you should aim to conquer it in week 2 or 3. With three towns, you should be perfectably capable to handle the final opponent. So, build up as much as you like.

Comment: Meanwhile I managed to win. I realised that it was possible to upgrade the troops which also gave extra troops per turn which were more than enough to take out the eastern orcs (big oversight on my part, still getting used to the UI). In addition to that I took reinforcement skill and heal to avoid losing many troops in combat.